Creating 2 custom delay retry topics using spring kafka ver 3.1.4
We have implemented spring kafka delayed retry using custom topic naming strategy(SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC) and RetryTopicNamesProvider to provide the custom retry topic name and this is working fine.
We have another scanario in which we want to define another delayed retry topic with custom naming.
The RetryTopicNamesProvider only provides the topic name for one use case where I want to customize the delay topic name for single topic.
I tried to use multiple listeners for same topic as given in https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/retrytopic/multi-retry.html
However, the messages are getting mixed up between the 2 listeners.
Is it possible to configure multiple(or 2) retry topics with custom naming ?
